# Are TCP connections within a host aware of one another?

Tags: tcp

I was wondering how a typical TCP/IP stack of a Windows or a Linux machine works in terms of congestion control. So, are active TCP connections within the OS aware of one another? I mean, the actual algorithm of a single TCP connection instance, is aware about other existing TCP connections and if yes, does it use this info to better handle bandwidth and resources in general? Or does each TCP connection algorithm only rely on the "well-known" congestion control mechanisms like the TCP window, retransmissions, etc., to handle congestion control?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about hosts/servers are off-topic here. You could try to ask about that on [su]. The theory of TCP is on-topic, but the specific host implementations are not.

Comment: Well, @RonMaupin, if TCP in ON topic, and TCP implementations live in hosts and OSs... how exactly would I set a case without mentioning hosts and servers? Nevermind...

Comment: Protocol theory is on-topic, but specific protocol implementations in hosts are not. You are asking about host OS implementations of TCP. What happens inside a host is off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> are active TCP connections within the OS aware of one another?

Generally not, at least not more than TCP connections are "aware" of any traffic flowing over a local NIC or along a used network path.

TCP's congestion mechanism needs to deal with congestion, no matter where it happens.

However, implementations vary and many are closed source, so we can never be entirely sure.